# Why cant I just import everything?

Tags: java, import

I love Java. I have heard a lot of bad things about java on how it is slow and all, but for me, it seems like a better alternative to C and C++. The only reason that I don't like java is because the standard library is **SO BIG** and it takes forever to just set up all of the `import` statements in my code. Why can't I just do

```
import java.*;
```

and have all of my import statements in one neat package. I am not making a big program so speed is not an issue. Thank you!

Comment: It smells like a fake problem. Why do you want this?

Comment: Sure, it's a pain if you're writing Java unassisted. That's why we have IDEs to insert import statements for us.

Comment: Import doesn't do what you think it does. It's importing namespaces for your code, so you don't need to fully-qualify names. Such a feature would be the same as doing away with namespaces entirely.

Comment: So that when I am making apps, I dont have to list 30 import statements at the top of the file.

Comment: Why don't you use an IDE to do this for you? (And part of the answer is that real applications import lots of libraries that might have classes named the same thing and you have to make it unambiguous which one you want.)

Comment: It's not slow. In any case, narrowing imports, within reason, avoids having no idea what your code actually uses before going through all of it.

Comment: You could list none. Or, just the ones that help you write your code more succinctly

Comment: @Andrew Barber♦ oooooh.... ok I understand now... thank you... I am a java noob. srry for bad question

Comment: Heh; no worries! We've all been there!

Answer (score 3):

Import statements are only for the aid of the developer, at runtime they've been used to fully qualify the classes anyway. Further, it's very similar to the namespace feature in C++ and you wouldn't want to make everything a global there either (although Java does effectively `import` `java.lang.*` by default). Finally, a free IDE like `eclipse` or `Netbeans` will help manage import(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few classes (especially common or basic classes) that have the same name but are parts of different packages. They are thus different code, doing different things, or the same things in different ways. Consider the Hibernate and JPA entity classes as just one of many examples. If you imported everything, you would have no way to control which class is actually compiled and used. Using an IDE, like so many are recommending, lets you see the possibilities and choose the one you really need (and the IDE will then usually automatically write the import statement for you). 
On the flip side, there is nothing wrong with fully qualifying all your classes. It just is wordy and not elegant.
So you see that the import statements don't really import anything, they are just conveniences to avoid having to prepend all your classes with packages.